# fade in/out and textView

Tags: android

Using

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein,R.anim.fadeout)
```

change a default animation with (R.anim.fadein/out).

In my code I've a button listener to change a textView:

```
textView1.setText(""+prog[x])
```

Can I use this R.anim.fadein/out when I click on button? (when the text are change)

Comment: If you want to _fade out_ the old text and _fade in_ the new text then no, you can't do it. You need a `TextSwitcher` to do that